# Problems with microphone in google meet

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, google

I have a laptop Levovo v110 with Ubuntu 20.04.

I had a problem with the microphone: it wasn't working, but I found [this](https://qna.habr.com/q/632949) solution (it's in Russian, sorry). I set the Right Channel slider to the zero position as it is in this image.
[image]

So the microphone started working normally, but when I opened Google Meet, the Right Channel slider returned to the position it had had before, as it is in this image.
[image]

So, I want to "freeze" the Right Channel slider in the zero position. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.